# How do Void and absurd work

Tags: purescript

Source code for `Void` states:

```
newtype Void = Void Void

instance showVoid :: Show Void where
    show = absurd

absurd :: forall a. Void -> a
absurd a = spin a
    where
    spin (Void b) = spin b
```

It seems `Void` is an infinitely recursive type, while `absurd` is an infinitely recursive function. I tried running `show ((unsafeCoerce "lol") :: Void)` in the REPL and it promptly went into an infinite loop.

What bothers me here is the type signature of `absurd :: forall a. Void -> a`. How is the signature valid? Does the compiler recognize infinitely recursive functions and allow them to have any return type knowing they will never actually terminate if called? Wouldn't just having `absurd = unsafeCoerce` have the same effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the compiler doesn't recognize infinitely looping functions. That is actually known to be impossible - see [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

The signature is valid, because there is nothing in the function body that would determine (or have any effect on) what the return type should be. Therefore, the return type can be anything. As simple as that.

---

The point of `Void` is that it's a type that cannot have any values at all. Like an empty set. In this case, that property is achieved via the clever trickery of making every value of `Void` contain another value of `Void`, thus making it impossible to construct a value of `Void`. This means that, for all practical purposes, the type `Void` cannot have any values.

The corresponding function `absurd` is a function that can never be called. This property follows from the function taking `Void` as argument. Since there can be no values of type `Void`, it is impossible to provide arguments for such function, and thus it is impossible to call it. Such function is useful in some very high-brow edge cases, but mostly it is a theoretical curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

The implementation of `absurd` doesn't really matter, as it's not possible to have a value of `Void` - there's no way to construct it. That's also why it's safe to have such a function - it's not making something out of nothing, it just will never happen, so it's only used for evidence for the type checker. So yep, `unsafeCoerce` could also be used safely.

But yes, an infinitely recursive function can be typed as having whatever return type and that will type check - it's not a specific feature encoded in the type checker, it's just falls out from the other rules that we have. One way of looking at it, is since the function is infinitely recursive, there's no evidence to contradict whatever you state the return type as being.